# ASP.NET Listview Data Question

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a asp.Net ListView Control, and before the Data is bound to the controls
 example <%# Eval("NAME") %> I want use that to set it to a property of another control. I am not sure of what method to run such as onitemcreated, ondatabindind etc. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a objectDataSource instead of a SQLDataSource.